# Android Studio layout stuck emulating old version, does not reflect changes to design

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin, layout

My Android Studio app (a decision maker) compiles without any errors and works as intended. However, when I emulate or even run the app on my phone the layout is an old version of my app. Any changes that I make to the activity_main.xml do not reflect when I run the app.

I am running the latest version of AS: 4.1.2

Here is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/addTopicBtn"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
    android:layout_width="158dp"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:cursorVisible="false"
    android:fontFamily="@font/muli_bold"
    android:text="Add Topic"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/chooseTopicBtn"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/selectedTopicText" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/selectedTopicText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/muli_bold"
    android:text="Topic"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.359" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/chooseTopicBtn"
    style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Button.Borderless"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:fontFamily="@font/muli_bold"
    android:text="Button"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop"
    tools:text="Choose Topic" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/addTopicText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:fontFamily="@font/muli_bold"
    android:hint="add new topic"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/chooseTopicBtn"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.576" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="27dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="45dp" />

<Switch
    android:id="@+id/switch1"
    android:layout_width="188dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:text="Switch"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="127dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="119dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the actual layout:

[image]

And here is what it looks like when I run it:

[image]

Here is what I have tried so far:

-Created an entirely new and unrelated project in android studio and ran into the same issue.

-Restarted my computer

-Restarted AS

-Invalidate caches/Restart

-Uninstall/Reinstall AS

-Delete all AS files/folders in Program Files

-Delete the .android folder in C:\Users\Me

-Wipe data from virtual emulator

-Create new virtual emulator

-Run on actual phone

-Force refresh layout

-Enable Autoconnection to Parent

-Disable Autoconnection to Parent

Any help in solving this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After attempting to build the project from scratch and attempting to manually copy my code I found that AS had created a second activity_main.xml file that was being used. It was probably an automatic suggestion that I clicked on without thinking about it or really understanding what was being done.

[image]

Deleting it caused issues so I am now just using the second xml file and changes are updating normally.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is screen size. use RelativeLayout as parent layout or try the same device as you are using in Android Studio Preview.

Comment: I erased the xml file and made a new one with RelativeLayout, but it still shows the old layout and doesn't show any changes.